# Create a Table only Schema

Tags: sql-server-2005

We use JPA to create the objects that map to our database tables, however whenever it starts looking at our views the entire entity generation process grinds to a halt.

Is there a way in SQL Server to create a schema that only has access to the tables in our database?

Comment: It sounds like your best approach may be to create a database user that only have rights to tables, and have your entity-creating application use that database principal to connect.

Comment: Is there a way to make the user get all tables? Specifically I'd want new tables to be automatically added to his security, otherwise it just becomes a pain in the ass to have to constantly update it.

Comment: Put your tables in SchemaX, "other stuff" in SchemaY, grant the user access to just SchemaX? However, feels "icky" doing this just to satisfy the needs of a development tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this isn't perfect put it works well enough for me.
Note this is a development database where we're trying to make life easier for the developers rather than a production database.

What i did was create a TablesOnly user that people must login with when they're generating entities.
I had 2 scenarios that I had to deal with - Current tables and tables that will be created in the future.

First I ran this cursor to allocate the current tables to my 'TablesOnly' user

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(50) -- username  
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(50) -- database name  

SELECT @username = 'tablesOnly'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM sys.tables


OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

        EXECUTE ('GRANT SELECT ON '+@tablename+' TO '+@username)
        EXECUTE ('GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '+@tablename+' TO '+@username)

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @tablename   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Then I created this trigger on a table create that automatically allocated the permissions that I need to the user

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTablesOnlyUser 
ON DATABASE 

    FOR CREATE_TABLE
    AS 
        set nocount on

        DECLARE @data XML, @ObjectName sysname
        set @data = EVENTDATA()
        SET @ObjectName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname')


        PRINT 'GRANT SELECT ON '+@objectName+' TO tablesOnly'
        PRINT 'GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '+@objectName+' TO tablesOnly'
        EXECUTE ('GRANT SELECT ON '+@objectName+' TO tablesOnly')
        EXECUTE ('GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON '+@objectName+' TO tablesOnly')
```